# Getting Latitude & longitude of Mollweide projection using GeoTools

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools

I am very new to GeoTools and map projections.

I have a map with a size of X,Y Pixels and it is in Mollweide projection.

How can I manage in Java code to find the long/latitude of a specific point ( X1,X2 ) in my map?

The 'Java Map Projection Library' was mentioned in a comment. I tried to do the transformation with JMPL, but I guess I have a lack of understanding.

How can I tell the transformation my map size ( X,Y ) or how shall I do the transformation ?

My Code so far:

```
    Point2D.Double pointonmap = null;
Point2D.Double latlon = null;
MolleweideProjection molproj=new MolleweideProjection();

pointonmap = new Point2D.Double (1400,1000);  

latlon=molproj.inverseTransform(pointonmap,new Point2D.Double ());

System.out.println("latlon: " + latlon.getX() + ", " + latlon.getY());
```